# UWP for web site development

Tags: css

I was reading about UWP (universal windows platform) design guidelines on MS website. This is mostly about applications, not websites. However, is there something similar from MS when I want my desktop application and website to have the same look and feel. Is there anyone aware of a website template that follows these guidelines?

Answer (score 4):

The closest things I've seen are WinJS (http://www.buildwinjs.com/) and Metro UI (http://metroui.org.ua/)

Be sure to check out all of the examples for both projects.

Comment: Yes, but in the WinJS sites and docu it states that they "only support fixes" but "do not plan for any future versions".... as such, don't think that going for WinJS is really a choice for the future

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses same icons, types and color schemes what they use it for Apps. Currently they don't have any website guidelines.

They have guidelines for Apps in Desktop.

In order to make your app looks similar to MS Design,

I suggest use same icons, colors and Types for your website. 
Take a reference from OneDrive website, they have included almost every kind of interactions.

[Click Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/design) <- link might help you.